# A problem on complete metric space

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Prove: If $f\in C^{\infty}[a,b]$, and $\forall x\in[a,b]$, $\exists n\in \mathbb{N}$, $\forall m>n$, $f^{(m)}(x)=0$, then $f$ is a polynomial.

It's a problem I got from Zorich's Mathematical Analysis Vol.II, Chap 9.5 Prob. 2(b).

Comment: Does $n$ depends on $x$?

Comment: Yes, for different $x$ there is different $n$.

Comment: [Perhaps overkill](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/34059/if-f-is-infinitely-differentiable-then-f-coincides-with-a-polynomial), but this can be done using the Baire Category theorem (with weaker assumptions, I'd add).

Comment: @T.Bongers: From the title might be it is not an overkill? ^^

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly the solution I am looking for!

Answer (score 1):

*This is a community wiki answer designed to help eliminate this question from the unanswered queue*

---

The OP was totally satisfied by [this solution to the problem](https://mathoverflow.net/a/34067/19965) on mathoverflow.